# Buildbot (from buildbot.net) : iCloud email not working as Status Target

Tags: python, smtp, twisted, buildbot

I am setting up buildbot to use an iCloud email address as Status Target :

```
m = mail.MailNotifier(fromaddr="some_icloud_user@me.com",
                  sendToInterestedUsers=False,
                  extraRecipients=["some_other_icloud_users@me.com"],
                  useTls=True, relayhost="smtp.mail.me.com", smtpPort=587,
                  smtpUser="some_icloud_user@me.com", smtpPassword="some_icloud_password")
```

(the iCloud email setup instructions are [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US_)).

Seems like there's something wrong with the TLS/SSL handshake (from master/twistd.log) :

```
2014-06-09 00:43:34-0700 [ESMTPSender,client] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 1
2014-06-09 00:43:34-0700 [ESMTPSender,client] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ionut/work/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-14.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 214, in doRead
        return self._dataReceived(data)
      File "/Users/ionut/work/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-14.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 220, in _dataReceived
        rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
      File "/Users/ionut/work/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-14.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 571, in dataReceived
        why = self.lineReceived(line)
      File "/Users/ionut/work/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-14.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/twisted/mail/smtp.py", line 1063, in lineReceived
        why = self._okresponse(self.code,'\n'.join(self.resp))
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/Users/ionut/work/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-14.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/twisted/mail/smtp.py", line 1411, in esmtpState_starttls
        self.transport.startTLS(self.context)
    exceptions.AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'startTLS'
2014-06-09 00:43:34-0700 [ESMTPSender,client] Unhandled error in Deferred:
2014-06-09 00:43:34-0700 [ESMTPSender,client] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: twisted.mail.smtp.TLSError: 451 Could not complete the SSL/TLS handshake
    <<< 250-NO-SOLICITING
    <<< 250 SIZE 28311552
    >>> STARTTLS
    <<< 220 2.5.0 Go ahead with TLS negotiation.
```

Note : I am NOT able to send email from the command line via "mail" or "sendmail" - I didn't bother since I noticed buildbot has its own email client Python code.

Please help - thank you !

Comment: You might also tag this as "twisted"

Comment: thank you, just did (python newbie here, btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it : since buildbot uses virtualenv, I needed to install pyOpenSSL via easy_install - in the directory that contains the local python env (i.e., the "sandbox") I ran "easy_install pyopenssl" and the SSL handshake proceeded correctly, so buildbot can send emails now. Initially, I "installed" pyOpenSSL by linking to the SSL directory from inside the system Python framework. Looks like the buildbot install script doesn't install pyOpenSSL, weird. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

With all of the anti-spam measures in place these days, the strategy of sending mail directly to the recipient's mail server is unlikely to work very well.  You would do better to either use your organization's SMTP server.

That aside, I suspect that the problem here is that you don't have pycrypto installed, or are using a Twisted reactor that doesn't support TLS.

Comment: buildbot uses virtualenv to set up its environment. I see there's ssl and crypto related files in the virtualenv directory - I had to install them manually, by linking them from my Python.framework system library.

Comment: BTW, I see this Twisted reactor in the site-packages dir : sandbox//lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-14.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/

Comment: The virtualenv directory has python 2.7 and my system framework is 2.6 - could this be a problem with linking OpenSSL into the virtualenv dir ? lrwxr-xr-x  1 ionut  staff  82 Jun  8 23:52 sandbox/lib/python2.7/OpenSSL -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL